# How to make a character in Rimworld with specific stats?

Tags: rimworld

I want to make a scenario, where two friends crash-landed on a frozen tundra planet. These two friends have specific skills, injuries and start with a very high and positive relationship.

Through the scenario editor I can choose starting items, research items etc, I can even choose the planet I start on, but I don't understand how do I edit the stats of the starting characters? Do I need to get into modding for that or is there already an interface for that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with the mod [Prepare Carefully](https://ludeon.com/forums/index.php?topic=6261.0).

The above link has download locations, or the mod can be found on the Steam Workshop

Answer (score 1):

The [scenario editor](https://rimworldwiki.com/wiki/Scenario_system) does not allow you to create specific characters for a scenario. The main idea behind Rimworld scenarios is that with good planning, a player can "win" even with less-than-stellar starting pawns. Players can try to min-max their starting power by rerolling a bunch of times (or by using the Prepare Carefully mod, as Studoku mentions), but it should not be *required* to win.